# Busy waiting and shared memory

Tags: c, fork

I am currently trying to implement a single C program that creates a shared memory area for a given process then forks this process into one child, makes the child to write into a given position of the shared memory and has the father wait for until the child writes in that position. I used a simple busy waiting approach, suffering the parent process to wait until the child end his writing using a while loop. The problem is that it only works when I introduce some delay in that loop. Anyone has any idea why is this so?

Code:

```
int shmid;
int *shmptr;
int i, j, ret;

key_t key = SHM_KEY;

// Create shared memory segment
if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) < 0)
{
    printf("shmget error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

// Attach shared memory segment
if ((shmptr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == (void *) -1)
{
    puts("shmat error");
    return -1;
}   

shmptr[6] = '%';

ret = fork();
if (ret > 0) 
{/*parent*/
    /*here is the loop that implements the busy waiting approach*/
    while (shmptr[6] != '^') {
        sleep(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) printf("%c", shmptr[i]);
    puts("");

    int status = 0;
    wait(&status);
}
else 
{/*child*/
    shmptr[0] = 's';
    shmptr[1] = 'h';
    shmptr[2] = 'a';
    shmptr[3] = 'r';
    shmptr[4] = 'e';
    shmptr[5] = 'd';

    /*tell parent process ithas finished its writing*/
    shmptr[6] = '^';

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: How is shmptr declared? In particular, is it volatile?

Comment: Can you elaborate more your code OR post whole code?

Comment: "*it only works when I introduce some delay in that loop*" what happends without the delay, though?

Comment: Don't use busy waiting. Read [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html); I guess that the child is running and exiting too quickly

Comment: How did you compile? Did you try to `strace` ?

Comment: The compiler assumes the value of `shmptr[6]` doesn't change. For me, it ends jumping to an endless loop.

Comment: alk, without the delay the code bahaves as if the line shmptr[6] = '^' didn't exist, that is, the value '^' is never read. As ninjalj stated, it seems that the compiler is doing something like assuming the value does not change. But I have my concerns if that is really the case here, once it requires too much freedom for the compiler to do so, right?

Answer (score 1):

Volatile (see earlier comment will probably only work in a single-core scenario).  Assuming you are running on a CPU with more than one cores, you will need to treat access of every location in the shared memory region atomically.  If using a C++11 compliant compiler, each location of the region would need to be assumed to be of type `std::atomic<int>`.

Since you are probably using C, not C++, and using GCC, consider using the atomic builtins [GCC Atomic Builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

So, your

```
shmptr[0] = 's';
```

statement should be replaced with an atomic set operator:

```
_sync_val_compare_and_swap(&shmptr[0], 's');
```

And do the equivalent for all of the sets.  Then, do the equivalent in the loop to check for the return value (which will be the character you want).

The semaphore in another answer might work, but, there are no guarantees that the other locations will have made it through the CPUs write-post circuitry, through the cache controller on the source, and so on through the receiving CPU's controller, especially if the addresses being accessed span cache lines.

I would also recommend doing a sleep(0) or yield() of some sort to allow other programs to get time slices on the core that the main program is running on, otherwise, you will waste CPU resources.

Answer (score 0):

You want to synchonise access to the share memory (SHM).

This, for can example, be done by using a semphore.

1. Before `fork()`ing off the child call [`sem_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html).
2. Make the parent wait on [`sem_wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) prior to reading the SHM.
3. Have the child call [`sem_post()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html) when done writing the SHM.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what is happening is that the child is terminating too quickly.

You might use a non-hanging [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and add it in your loop:

```
/*here is the loop that implements the busy waiting approach*/
int status= 0;
while (shmptr[6] != '^') {
    if (waitpid(ret, &status, WNOHANG) == ret) break;
    sleep(1);
}
```

However, as I commented, ***busy waiting* is *always* bad in Linux user-space programs** (at the very least it is stressing your system). Read [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), or alternatively, set up a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) or an [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) or a [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) it. Or set up a `SIGCHLD` signal handler (read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) which just sets a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag to be tested in your loop.

You should also declare `volatile int*shmptr;` because the compiler might have optimized its use.